# Consistency errors for a SharePoint database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption, sharepoint

When I check my database (SQL Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2, SharePoint 2007 DB) with the command:

```
DBCC CheckDB
```

I get 12 consistency errors (see below).

Is the only way to fix it with `repair_allow_data_loss`?

Is there also a way to get the filename and delete the file in my SharePoint?

```
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data): Page (1:5718) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data), page (1:5718). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12584969 and -4.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:5718), slot 0, text ID 410976256 is referenced by page (1:5682), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data): Page (1:62999) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data), page (1:62999). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12584969 and -4.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:62999), slot 0, text ID 1788739584 is referenced by page (1:62231), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data): Page (1:72779) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data), page (1:72779). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12584969 and -4.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057594044940288 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:72779), slot 0, text ID 1898315776 is referenced by page (1:72782), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057599818924032 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 1898315776 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:72370:23)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057599818924032 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 410976256 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:72375:20)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057599643549696, alloc unit ID 72057599818924032 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 1788739584 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:72448:16)
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 12 consistency errors in table 'AllDocStreams' (object ID 293576084).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 12 consistency errors in database 'DatabaseName'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DatabaseName).
```

Answer (score 3):

Restore from your backup if possible.

"Allow data loss" is really a terrible option.

This excellent article will help you:

http://www.sql-server-pro.com/dbcc-checkdb.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently gave a pretty robust explanation on how to handle corruption issues [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25754/unknown-database-corruption-data-error-in-cyclic-redundancy-check/27037#27037).

Give that a look.  I would try dropping / recreating the indexes first, if it does not fix the issue you may have to run the repair_allow_data_loss in your case.

Comment: Since the indexID is 1 that means it's the clustered index and actual table storage.  CHECKDB is capable of figuring out whether or not teh corruption can be fixed by dropping and recreating indexes and will say to use repair_rebuild.  And, lastly, since repair_allow_data_loss may result in logical corruption (in this case record that a list exists but no information on what's in it) restoring from the last good backup is a better choice.

Comment: It is possible to search for the object or partition id in the database? ( I can´t find this id´s in my database, only guids.)